# Create DNS record for pod in Kubernetes for internal usage

Tags: kubernetes

I have this Helm chart which I use for deployment of microservice.

https://github.com/rcbandit111/external_domain_helm_chart_poc/tree/main/pod-chart

Several Microservices need to make a internal API calls to this microservice. How I can set internal DNS name for this pod so that can be available via unique custom name for other pods?

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what `Services` are for.

Create a Service resource targeting your pod and name them whatever you like - as long as it's domain name compatible.

You can access the pod via `<servicename>.<namespace>.svc.cluster.local`. (see [k8s docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/#a-aaaa-records))

For cluster-external traffic you need `Ingress` resources.

Comment: Instead of using `<servicename>.<namespace>.svc.cluster.local` can I configure it to be only `<servicename>` using Service?

Comment: Not without messing with ClusterDNS directly. I've added a link to my answer, have a look at Kubernetes' docs.

Comment: Looks like I can add a record into `/etc/resolv.conf` and specify short name for a pod there?

Comment: Both `/etc/resolv.conf` and `/etc/hosts` are likely to be modified by Kubernetes, so modifying them is likely not a good idea. Adding a config drop in to ClusterDNS is the way to go - but again, you move beyond what's supported by Kubernetes.

Answer (score 0):

As per the other answer, services are the way forward.

However, as you are asking about DNS record for a pod, please be aware such a thing is available out of the box:

```
kubectl get pod nginx -o wide                    
NAME    READY   STATUS    RESTARTS      AGE   IP           NODE             NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
nginx   1/1     Running   8 (14m ago)   47d   10.1.3.220   docker-desktop   <none>           <none>

kubectl run client --image nginx -it --rm -- bash

curl -I 10-1-3-220.default.pod
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
...

curl -I 10-1-3-220.default.pod.cluster.local
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
...
```

`default` is the namespace name.

Technically speaking it is possible to create a pod-level DNS entry pointing at a given IP address. That IP can be e.g. another pod's IP address:

```
cat client.yaml 
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    run: client
  name: client
spec:
  hostAliases:
  - hostnames: [nginx]
    ip: 10.1.3.220
  containers:
  - image: nginx
    name: client
    resources: {}
  dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
  restartPolicy: Always
status: {}

kubectl apply -f client.yaml
kubectl exec client -it -- curl -I nginx
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
...
```

However, this obviousy won't help if the pod gets recreated with a new IP address etc.

Comment: Instead of using `10-1-3-220.default.pod.cluster.local` can I configure it to be only `nginx` using Service?

Comment: See edited answer for example how to do that. Proceed with caution.